# Cache miss measurements: perf_event results are entirely different than VTune

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, caching

I am measuring the L1 & LLC cache miss rates for a few rival algorithms for searching over sorted data. The [benchmark](https://github.com/learnedsystems/SOSD) that I am analysing measures the cache miss rates of each algorithm using `linux/perf_event.h`. However, I realised that the L1-miss and LLC-miss rates measured by perf_event don't make sense.

For example, for binary search (`std::lower_bound`) over 200M uint64 values, the algorithm only accesses log2(200M) = 27 memory locations. Considering that some of the accesses will be cached, I expect both L1 and LLC misses to be 20-something, but the benchmark reports:

**L1-misses=87.29, LLC-misses=185.30**

First of all, how is it possible that the L1 miss rate is less than LLC miss rate? I suppose all LLC misses were caused by an L1-miss, no?

Besides, when I manually run the algorithms in Intel VTune (the GUI) and see the miss-rates on each section, the miss rates are entirely different and are close to what I expect (For binary search: LLC miss rate = 20.3).

Why are the cache miss rates so different when measured by perf_event? I am just very confused.

Is the code measuring the wrong probes? Here is the code:

```
registerCounter("L1-misses", PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE, 
    PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_L1D|(PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ<<8)|(PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS<<16));
registerCounter("LLC-misses", PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE, PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES);
```

and `registerCounter()` is defined as:

```
void registerCounter(const std::string& name, uint64_t type, uint64_t eventID) {
      names.push_back(name);
      events.push_back(event());
      auto& event = events.back();
      auto& pe = event.pe;
      memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
      pe.type = type;
      pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
      pe.config = eventID;
      pe.disabled = true;
      pe.inherit = 1;
      pe.inherit_stat = 0;
      pe.exclude_kernel = false;
      pe.exclude_hv = false;
      pe.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_ENABLED | PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_RUNNING;
   }
```

You might want to see the code [in the original repo](https://github.com/learnedsystems/SOSD/blob/87d34efbabbd9cd0a1c30502886f12c81cbd9727/utils/perf_event.h#L67)).

Comment: I suppose `C` is a good tag as the `linux/perf_event.h` library is for `C` ([see this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L71)), and also the part of the code that matters, is not C++-specific.

Comment: Possible you do have a reason to have both tags, ( `const std::string` is `C++` ), but contents of header file that supports `C`, and some universally understood constructs do not necessarily drive the `C` tag.   A `C++` compiler is required here (due to the prototype syntax.), that much is evident.

Comment: What I mean is that I suppose the key issue is how the `PERF_COUNT_*` values are combined via bitwise operators, and that's something that most knowledgable people of that thing are pure `C` geeks.